# ExactTarget Soap API: How can the ExtractResult be used to retrieve the status of an ExtractRequest?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, soap, data-export

The ExtractResult object has no supported methods listed on the ExactTarget SOAP API page for ExtractResult. The object is intended to retrieve the results of an ExtractRequest

How can the ExtractResult be used to retrieve the status of an ExtractRequest?

Is this object functional in the API? Here is the link to the documentation page: http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/extractresult/